# ui-grid (ng-grid) calculated width is too wide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have a dashboard with a sidebar. I am trying to use ui-grid in the main part (called dynamic-content) Here is my html:

```
<div class="dynamic-content col-lg-12">
<div id="account-grid" ui-grid="accountsVM.gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

The grid is showing up and rendering what I expect but the problem is that it is expanding (width-wise) well out of the bounds of the page causing a scrollbar to appear so that the entire grid can be viewed. I suspect that it is calculating its width based on the entire page width rather than based on its parent div. How can I deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forgot your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a css class to set the width of the grid:

```
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

And, if this is not fixed, the [auto-resize](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/213_auto_resizing) feature will enable the grid to resize itself when its container changes size.